# Cannot get Nested Object to show in DataGrid as Nested Datgrid Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, nested

I am new to WPF and XAML but am picking it up fairly quick I think.

I have a custom project I'm working on that has some objects built out like below. All the data is stored in XML files and loaded into the objects on startup. Note, I'm changing names for sack of privacy on the code/application.

- Overarching Class, let's call it Classrooms in a school
  Contains a property of Classrooms as ObservableCollection
  Uses INotifyPropertyChanged
- Primary Object Class, let's call it Classroom. Contains unique properties about the object and a property of Students as ObservableCollection
  Uses INotifyPropertyChanged
- Secondary Object Class, let's call it. Contains unique properties about the student and a property of Supplies as ObservableCollection
  Uses INotifyPropertyChanged
- Third Object Class, let's call it SupplyItem. Contains unique properties about the object.
  Uses INotifyPropertyChanged

My desire is to have a DataGridView on my MainWindow have a bound instance of the Overarching Collection Class. Each row should represent a Primary Object (Classroom) and show it's properties.

Each Row should have an expander button to expand the row and view a DataGrid with rows for each of the Secondary Object's (Student) associated to the Primary Objects.

The Third object will come later in a separate data grid. I need to get this first part working.

I am struggling to make this work. I have tried so many different ways to do this through XAML I've lost count. Nothing is working.

Intellisense in XAML shows that each property and ItemSource is mapped appropriately. There are no build errors. However, when debugging, I can see eah Primary Object listed in the rows. On expanding Rows that have Secondary Objects, the DataTable Appears, but there is no data listed in the table.

I have also used the Live Property Explorer and Live Visual Tree. I can see all the Primary Objects in the Visual Tree as Rows in the data grid. I can even go into the associated Secondary objects and see the necessary properties for those. I cannot however, get this to display in a working application.

Please help! What am I doing wrong? Greatly appreciate the help.

**Overarching Classrooms Class**

```
    public class Classrooms : ClassroomBaseClass
    {
        private static ObservableCollection<Classroom> _colls;
        public ObservableCollection<Classroom> Colls
        {
            get { return _colls; }
            set
            {
                _colls = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObservableCollection<Classroom>));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Primary Object Class (Classroom)**

```
    public class Classroom : ClassroomBaseClass
    {
        private Guid? _classroomId;
        public Guid? ClassroomId
        {
            get { return _classroomId; }
            set
            {
                _classroomId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ClassroomId));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
        public ObservableCollection<Job> Students
        {
            get { return _students; }
            set
            {
                _students = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Students));
            }
        }

    }
```

**Secondary Object Class, Student**

```
    public class Student : StudentBaseClass
    {
        private Guid? _studentId;
        public Guid? StudentId
        {
            get { return _studentId; }
            set
            {
                _studentId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StudentId));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SupplyItem> _supplyitems;
        public ObservableCollection<SupplyItem> SupplyItems
        {
            get { return _supplyitems; }
            set
            {
                _supplyitems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SupplyItems));
            }
        }

    }
```

**Third Object Class, SupplyItem**

```
    public class SupplyItem : SupplyItemBaseClass
    {
        private Guid? _supplyId;
        public Guid? SupplyId
        {
            get { return _supplyId; }
            set
            {
                _supplyId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SupplyId));
            }
        }

    }
```

**XAML - Top of XAML**

```
xmlns:appObjects="clr-namespace:App.Objects"

<Window.DataContext>
        <appObjects:Classrooms/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ClassroomDataGrid"                                           RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"                            RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="ClassroomDataGrid_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"
Margin="30,60,30,10"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Colls}">

<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#666666" />
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
           <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="GUID" Binding="{Binding Path=ClassroomId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        CanUserResize="True"
        Width="200" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Students Expander" Width="100">

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="appObjects:Classroom">
                    <Expander Width="50"
                         Expanded="Expander_Expanded"
                         Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"
                         IsExpanded="{Binding Expanded,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
         <DataTemplate >
            <DataGrid x:Name="StudentDataGrid"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      Margin="15,8,8,8"
                      Width="1000"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Coll.Students}">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Student Id"
                       Binding="{Binding Path =StudentId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Width="Auto"
                       Visibility ="Hidden"/>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: please format you code and fix indents. it is hard to see which tags are nested

Comment: Sorry, that should be better. I've been looking at the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate and in the DataTemplate setting the DataType there - but that results in the same error when binding Students to the DataGrid and binding each Student property to the columns of the DataGrid. Error: "Cannot resolve property 'Students' in data context of type 'App.Objects.Classrooms'"

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide to help solve the issue? What am I missing - I need help on this and the Question is being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

in the `StudentDataGrid` ItemsSource should be `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}"` instead of `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Coll.Students}"`

also make sure you have some columns in that DataGrid which are not hidden:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="StudentDataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Margin="15,8,8,8"
          Width="1000"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Student Id"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=StudentId}"
                        Width="Auto"/>

  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks ASh. I have tried this, however I get the error "Cannot resolve property 'Students' in data context of type 'App.Objects.Classrooms'". I believe this is happening because it's getting it's data context from the parent data grid. How can I change the data context of the expanded data grid? I've looked into several ways of doing this but have not been successful.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the comment on the columns. I have additional columns as well, I just removed from the code to not clutter the issue. The columns when on still do not show data.

Comment: I've also been looking at setting another Window.DataContext and referencing it in the datatable. This however states the DataContext is set more than once...<Window.DataContext>
        <appObjects:Classrooms/>
        <appObjects:Students x:Key="StudentModel" />
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: ASh is right about the DataContext, the details section inherits the context of the ROW that it's showing details for, not of the parent grid.  Are you getting that warning in VS or an actual running code?  My guess is the first, which is just because the designer isn't always great about knowing context.  You can fix that though by telling it what type to expect in your template like this: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appObjects:Student}`.  Important note that this template will then ONLY apply to objects of that type so if no details show up that means the object is not the right type.

Comment: One other quick comment, in the overall class your `nameof` in the property setter is wrong, it should be the name of the property, not the type.  Just as a matter of preference on collections I almost always make them get only and initialize on class construction.  That way the collection itself is never null, you just modify what objects are in the collection as I've found you almost never want to actually change the collection itself.

Comment: Thanks @sfaust. I'll look at making those changes to the classes property notifications. The error messages I'm getting those in VS - running the code it runs and shows the Classrooms in the datagrid in each row. Expanding them, I can see the DataGrid Header, but no content, even though it exists in the row in the Live Visual Tree. I'll try the DataTemplate DataType

Comment: @sfaust Thank you! Setting the DataTemplate DataType is what I had to do. As you mentioned I had to adjust the type to full understand what it was doing as at first it was not populating the datagrid. I'll post the solution of the XAML code.

Comment: Sorry yes yours should be classroom not student for the data type, good catch...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @ASh and @sfaust for helping me understand this. The answer was in the DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate / DataTemplate. We had to set the DataType here to the Classroom class as that is what each row represents. Then the DataGrid ItemSource is set to the Classroom ObservableCollection property for Students.

Here's the updated XAML code
'''

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="#666666" />
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
           <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="GUID" Binding="{Binding Path=ClassroomId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        CanUserResize="True"
        Width="200" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Students Expander" Width="100">

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="appObjects:Classroom">
                    <Expander Width="50"
                         Expanded="Expander_Expanded"
                         Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"
                         IsExpanded="{Binding Expanded,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type appObjects:Classroom}">
            <DataGrid x:Name="StudentDataGrid"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      Margin="15,8,8,8"
                      Width="1000"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students}">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Student Id"
                       Binding="{Binding Path =StudentId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Width="Auto"
                       Visibility ="Visible"/>

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

'''